# Como puedo imprimir estas matrices de formas sencilla

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, bucles, estructuras-de-datos

Bunas noches tengo dos problemas el primero quiero optimizar la impresión de las matrices, que me recomiendan hacer me gustarua tambien poder acortar las lineas de codigo , el segundo problemas es que me da error cuando ingreso un dato por teclado, me termina el codigo, nose porque el error sale asi si todo esta correcto, si alguien me puede ayudar seria de gran ayuda gracias

```
private void cocheNuevo(){
String [][] marca = {{"Ferrari "}, {"Lamborghini "}, {"Ford "}};
String [][] placas = {{"QWE123 "},{"ASD345 "},{"ZXC567 "}};
String [][] color = {{"Rojo "}, {"Rosado "}, {"Morado "}};
int [][] anioModelo = {{2020 }, {2019 }, {2018}};
double [][] preciosNuevos =  {{10.000 }, {9.000 }, {5.000}};
    for(String i[]:marca ){
        for(String o:i){
            System.out.print(o + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(String i[]:placas ){
        for(String o:i){
            System.out.print(o + "  ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(String i[]:color ){
        for(String o:i){
            System.out.print(o + "    ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i[]:anioModelo ){
        for(int o:i){
            System.out.print(o + "     ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(double i[]:preciosNuevos ){
        for(double o:i){ 
            System.out.print(o + "      ");
        }
    }
   }
```

Este es el problema ingreso a la opcion y enseguida da error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí, Este es el problema ingreso a la opcion y enseguida da error]

```
 public class Proyecto3 {

private Scanner sc;  
}
  private void desplegarMenu2() {
    mostrarOpciones2();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la opción: ");
    int opcionSeleccionada2 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());  //ingreso el dato y me da error
    ejecutarOpcion2(opcionSeleccionada2);
    desplegarMenu(); 
}


     private void ejecutarOpcion2(int opcionSeleccionada2) {
    switch (opcionSeleccionada2) {
        case 0:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Ingreso la opción: 1 " + "\n" + "Nuevo. ");
            
            
            cocheNuevo();
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Ingreso la opción: 2 " + "\n" + "Usado. ");
            cocheUsado();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Gracias por utilizer el Sistema.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo en tu código a ti no te hace falta usar matrices sino arreglos unidimensionales o vectores, por tanto tus arreglos quedarían asi:

```
String[] marca = {"marca1", "marca2", "marca3"};
```

Lo mismo harías para color y los otros datos. Como es un vector no te hace falta dos **ciclos for** sino uno solo y todos los valores de todos los arreglos pueden ser impresos con un solo **ciclo for** no con tantos como tienes en tu código, ahora tu código se reduciría a esto:

```
for(int i = 0; i < marca.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println(marca[i] + " " + placa[i] + " " + color[i] + " " + annioModelo[i] + " " + preciosNuevos[i]);
}
```

De esta forma imprimirias todos los datos que te hacen falta, en el **ciclo for** pongo **i < marca.length**, pero como todos los arreglos tienen la misma longitud puedes usar cualquiera.